# To merge cell vertically or horizontally

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge cells in DataGrid/AdvancedDataGrid in Adobe Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910625/how-to-merge-cells-in-datagrid-advanceddatagrid-in-adobe-flex)

I want to do something as Office Excel with Flex, such as merging cells. How do I do it?

Comment: Refer [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6910625/842112] and [http://stackoverflow.com/q/1569311/842112]

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please given below link you will find out every thing regarding your query....[Click Here For Demo & Code](http://code.google.com/p/flex-table/#Demo)

Comment: Thank you Mrugesh for your link.It is very useful.